# Why do I not receive the passthrough variables when PayPal completes a transaction

Tags: variables, paypal, pass-through

When PayPal completes a transaction it is supposed to return the pass-through variables like amount, item number, currency code, etc.
My app does not return those variables unless I am in the sandbox mode.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Methinks that I would ask that question of the good folk at PayPal.  I've found them to be extremely responsive and helpful with such inquiries.  (They *want* you to "do it right!")

Comment: Those are not 'pass-through variables'. Those are transaction variables. The only pass-through variables are `custom` and some way to pass an invoice number which I don't remember at the moment. It is not my experience that `amount` for example is not sent. I have an entire database table that proves the contrary. I suggest there is something wrong with your unposted code.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I will only say that that has not been my experience: on the contrary.

Comment: @EJP ... "your mileage may vary."  :-D

Comment: what are you checking exactly? I'm assuming you are talking about PDT?